# How can I get meshes to snap into place by pairing them with bones?

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I have a mesh and armature I'm importing into Blender as an FBX.  I'm having a chronic problem where characters are imported with fully functioning geometry and armature, but the eyes are importing as a separate mesh.

I've checked the armature with Noesis, and I found that there are two bones that are supposed to control the eyes.  Bone09 is for the left eye, and Bone11 is for the right eye. In Object mode in Blender, those two bones move correctly with the rest of the armature, but the eye meshes remain in a static position, separate from the head.  In Edit mode, when the armature and the mesh is zeroed in position and rotation, the eye meshes are in the proper place inside her head.

I have read somewhere that vertex groups and bones should have the same names, so I tried doing that with each eye and that didn't seem to work at all.

How can I get the meshes to assume their proper positions with the bones?

Comment: Join the eyes to the rest of the body, select the right eye vertices and assign them to the correct vertex group, same for the left eye

Comment: With your help, I think I figured it out.
1. Parent the eyes mesh to the body mesh.
2. Parent the eyes mesh to the body armature.
3. In Edit mode, select the vertices for each eye and assign them to the appropriate vertex groups, one at a time.

That seemed to have done it.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, parent the eyes to the body mesh + parent to the body armature? No, just join the eyes to the body mesh (Ctrl J), then assign the eyes meshes to the correct vertex groups

Comment: It doesn't work unless I parent the eyes mesh to both the body mesh and the armature.  If I don't do the second action, the list of vertex groups doesn't show up.

Comment: Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/